# How to use zip file which have all the package of nltk?

Tags: python

We need to import all the packages from the zip file using python code.

```
import zipfile
a = zipfile.Zipfile("Path",r)
```

After this we have zip file as `nltk` which is stored in local. So how we need to use it and run samplde code like below:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synsets('dog')
```

Comment: what do you mean by *After this we have zip file as nltk which is stored in local*?

Comment: we need to run this wordnet example using the nltk package which is stored in local as a zip file.Hope i'm clear this time

Comment: @AshimSinha So you have a zip-file that contains `nltk.corpus` with a class you call `wordnet`? Use `__import__`? Either edit your question to more accurately describe your problem and/or show the effort to solve it before asking a broad question, otherwise it will get flagged as "to broad", thank you :)

Comment: We have the nltk zip file and we need to import all the package from it and try to run a sample program of wordnet .

Comment: Actually our requirement is little different as we need to run the sample in azure ml which for time being don't have network access to download the package so we are using zip file as an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) module or

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/my/path/file.zip')
import my_module
my_module.caLL_something()
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but when we import the package it gives an error like cannot import name comtrans. We have downloaded the zip of nltk from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk .So, is there any other path from where we can download the zip file